# High memory utilizing when fetch data from stored procedure to DataTable

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I want to process millions of rows and doing some process on that and export that records into excel file. When I am fetching records and fill it into a `DataTable`, it is utilizing very large amount of memory - around 8 to 10 gb. My SQL query result is containing around 300 columns.

I have tried with batch and tried with `SqlDataReader` also. With and without batchwise it is taking almost same memory and after using `SqlDataReader` it is not impacting on memory. Below is my current code. Is there any way to stop this high utilization?

Fetch records in batches of 10000 rows:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

for (int i = 0; i <= 0; i++)
{
    int startRow = 1;
    int endRow = 10000;

    for (int j = 0; (startRow == 1 || dt.Rows.Count >= 10000); j++)
    {
        dt = null;
        dt = _dataService.SqlExecuteDT(data);
        startRow = startRow + 10000;
    }
}
```

Code for calling the stored procedure, and filling the datatable:

```
public static DataTable SqlExecuteDT(string spname, Dictionary<string, object> parameters, DBName dBName = DBName.DBCONN)
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(DBConnection.GetConnectionString(dBName)))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(spname, conn))
        {
            cmd.CommandTimeout = Timeout;
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            if (parameters != null)
            {
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> kvp in parameters)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(kvp.Key, kvp.Value ?? DBNull.Value);
            }

            conn.Open();

            // Use a forward-only, read-only data reader for memory efficiency
            using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess))
            {
                // Retrieve column schema
                DataTable schemaTable = reader.GetSchemaTable();

                // Create DataTable to hold the data
                DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

                // Add columns to DataTable based on schema
                foreach (DataRow row in schemaTable.Rows)
                {
                    string columnName = row["ColumnName"].ToString();
                    Type dataType = (Type)row["DataType"];
                    dataTable.Columns.Add(columnName, dataType);
                }

                // Populate DataTable with data
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    DataRow dataRow = dataTable.NewRow();

                    for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                    {
                        dataRow[i] = reader[i];
                    }

                    dataTable.Rows.Add(dataRow);
                }

                return dataTable;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is creating 3 copies of the table. All you really need is `return DataTable.Load(reader)` and no loops at all. BTW the code that creates the command and passes the parameters is bad and can be reduced to a few lines. `SqlExecuteDT` doesn't offer any benefits.

Comment: What does the table contain? 10K rows is no data at all. Even with 300 rows, you only have 3M values. Even with triplicate tables, each value would have to be at least 1KB large to get to 8GB.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Wrong. They keyword here is "Excel file". Most library to create excel files, create the xml dom tree in memory before compressing it into a zip file (thats what an excel file is: A zip file with xml strucutre). Creating the dom tree is very memory intensive and for every 1 MB of raw data you have to calculate with 14-28 MB of memory and more. Even more true if the library doesn't utlize the shared string tables that excel format offers and saves same values multiple times

Comment: As a small example, for 30k rows and 45 columns, you have to calculate around 1-2.5 GB of memory, depending on the efficiency of the library, i.e. see https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/releases/tag/0.100.0. Even with their optimization done in that release, the amount of memory used is MASSIVE. Now having 300 columns is almost 7 times as much. So 10k rows at 300 columns and you're easily at 5-8 GB. Only options there are use different more efficient library or export as CSV as its very memory efficient as you can write/stream it as you process it

Comment: There are multiple reasons for why that is the case, a DOM tree must be represtented as a object hierarcy. An DOM element has a name, and proeprties of each are strings, so there is a lot of pointer and references on the heap which use a lot of memory. So even to store a integer value (4 bytes) into an excel cell you need at least 4 dom elements (row, cell, val, style), more likely more. each of them having a name, and attributes (row number and cell/col) and a child node. thats at least 8 pointers,1 integer,4 objects,6-8 strings,2 integers plus all the overhead of  the classes (virtualtables)

Comment: 8 GB memory is occupied before going to generate excel file. I am just filling 1 million records in datatable which are returned from database.

Answer (score 2):

Your `SqlExecuteDT` function is overly complex. Everything you need is already available via `DataTable.Load`.

```cs
public static DataTable SqlExecuteDT(string spname, Dictionary<string, object?> parameters = null, DBName dBName = DBName.DBCONN)
{
    using var conn = new SqlConnection(DBConnection.GetConnectionString(dBName));
    using var cmd = new SqlCommand(spname, conn);
    cmd.CommandTimeout = Timeout;
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    if (parameters != null)
    {
        foreach (var kvp in parameters)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(kvp.Key, kvp.Value ?? DBNull.Value);
    }

    conn.Open();
    using SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess);

    var table = new DataTable();
    table.Load(reader);
    return reader;
}
```

And then your outer loop makes no sense at all. Why is there a loop there at all? It should be just:

```cs
var dt = _dataService.SqlExecuteDT(SomeProcName);
```

Comment: I was also tried with table.Load(reader) before the current code. It's execution is fast But there was no impact in memory utilization.  For loop is used for batching process. I have 1 million records and I am fetching it in 10k records batches.

Comment: You say "I am fetching it in 10k records batches" but your code doesn't show that, it shows you getting *all* of the data  on every loop. Perhaps there is some missing code where you merge the datatables, and where you pass through parameters?